# A1....A9 be a nine-sided regular polygon with side length 2. The difference between the lengths of A1A5 and A2A4 equals 2

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Let A1A2A3
....A9
be a nine-sided regular polygon with side length 2 units. The difference between the lengths
of the diagonals A1A5 and A2A4 equals $2$.

I can prove it very easily if I could have proved that the side $A_2 A_4$  is parallel to $A_1 A_5$ in the following picture.[image]

Is it possible to prove?

Comment: The figure you drew has ten sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  $\angle415\cong\angle142$, since they are inscribed angles that intercept congruent arcs of $\frac{360^\circ}9$.  Since those angles are alternate interior angles of the lines $\overline{24}$ and $\overline{15}$ cut by transversal $\overline{14}$, we conclude that $\overline{24}\parallel\overline{15}$.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer? I think there are some printing mistakes..@Matthew Daly

Comment: @sani What printing mistakes are you referring to?  I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Yea I misunderstood..@Matthew Daly